# How to make Emacs key-bindings work in minibuffer?

Tags: emacs

I have what some might consider a pretty spastic typing workflow, where I've remapped 'Alt Gr' to <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> and bound a bunch of symbols I've never in my life typed (ł€®þ←↓→œþæøłĸŋđðßª«»©“”nµ etc) to do more useful stuff.

This works great, except when the minibuffer opens for search+replace, open file, or something that requires kb input. Say I want Emacs to kill a buffer (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd>), but hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> instead which opens minibuffer for incremental search. Now I can just press (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd>) anyway, which executes kill-buffer as expected.

But say I rebound kill-buffer, i.e.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "ĸ") 'kill-buffer)         ;; altgr + k
```

If I do this inside the incremental search mini-buffer, Emacs simply inserts a ĸ. I have to cancel incremental search before I can access my keybinding. Is there a way around this?

Comment: 1. This is a duplicate question, in as much as it is about minibuffer keymaps. 2. However, Isearch uses its own keymap, `isearch-mode-map` - Isearch does *not* use the minibuffer (even though it looks like it does).